# CSS not being loaded rails nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, passenger

I have been trying to get my server running for the last couple of hours. I am using nginx and rails passenger.

In my public/assets folder I have all my precompiled assets, they have some kind of string appended to them such as logo-3464deb64640aad071fa1f29714cb888.png that im guessing is some kind of unique identifier.

When I go to my app in my browser, none of the images or css load. It seems rails is trying to load the css files without the id string, even though in the assets folder they do have this string.What's odd is that the JS seems to load okay.

Original source:

```
<!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine or request Chrome Frame -->
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

<!-- Use title if it's in the page YAML frontmatter -->
<title>1</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>

<!--csrf meta tags-->
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--default javascript-->
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Source in browser:

```
<!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine or request Chrome Frame -->
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

<!-- Use title if it's in the page YAML frontmatter -->
<title>1</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />


<!--csrf meta tags-->
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="+wxNNUVYmfRwayYxYOfVLWUEpm+iTH5BZN4Puluebh0=" name="csrf-token" />

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--default javascript-->
<script src="/assets/application-e5001548de09f8867b4c904b1630d600.js"></script>
```

Config:

```
FwnApp::Application.configure do
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

# Code is not reloaded between requests.
config.cache_classes = true

# Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
# your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
# and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
# Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
config.eager_load = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
# Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
# For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
# config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
# config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs.
config.assets.digest = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

# Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
# config.force_ssl = true

# Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
config.log_level = :info

# Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
# config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

# Use a different logger for distributed setups.
# config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

# Use a different cache store in production.
# config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
# config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already   added.
# config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

# Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
# Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise      delivery errors.
# config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
# the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
config.i18n.fallbacks = true

# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

# Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
# config.autoflush_log = false

# Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end

require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module FwnApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Application css

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

Application rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module FwnApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set to `true`:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

If still don't work, share your `application.rb` and `application.css` files.

**EDIT**

To add different css files you have two options:

1. Add them to the `application.css` manifest.
2. In `application.rb`: `config.assets.precompile += ['application.css', 'other.css']`

I suggest you to read the Rails [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to understand how asset pipeline works.

To add them depending on the page, in the application layout:

*application.html.haml*

```
...
= yield :css if content_for?(:css)
...
```

Then in any view:

*view.html.haml*

```
- content_for :css do
  stylesheet_link_tag 'other'
```

Make sure to add `other.css` as in **2**.

Comment: Thing is I want it to work with nginx, so I want nginx delivering the assets, and serve_static_assets will have rails serve them instead I believe?

Comment: I have added the files. I did, change those two setting above just to see what would happen. While the string was appended to the css file, it still 404d.

Comment: Also `application.rb`.

Comment: I got it working! For some reason my css files had not been precompiled beforehand, however when I added an application.css file and added my stylesheets they were precompiled. Previously I had `stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheet" is application.css required, what if I want different css for different pages